# Could not load file or assembly "Umbraco.ModelsBuilder" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, umbraco

## I have a problem with Umbraco backoffice when my site is online.

I published my site with Visual Studio 2015 and it works fine, but when i try to open the Umbraco backoffice i get an error that says

```
Could not load file or assembly "Umbraco.ModelsBuilder" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

but, in the folder bin the dll exists. When i test the project in local it works perfectly.

Could anyone give me some advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting all files and folders under `/bin/*` on your remote installation.

Then in Visual Studio `Rebuild Solution` and `Publish` again.

Additionally when anything in Umbraco doesn't work, always first delete the whole `/TEMP` folder under `/App_Data` and restart Umbraco.

Comment: Old post but for future reference: Deleting the `/TEMP` folder did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of the other dependencies missing. Compare what's in your /bin/ folder locally with what's on the live site's /bin/ folder and see if there's any DLLs missing. If they're not the same, copy up the missing files and see if that sorts out the problem for you.